In NextJS, is there a way to have a component always be dynamically loaded?
For example, if I have a modal component, that I always want to dynamically be lazy loaded:
// modal.tsx
export const ModalComponent = () => {...}


// component1.tsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const DynamicModal = dynamic(() => import('../components/modal.tsx'), {
  ssr: false,
})
...


// component2.tsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const DynamicModal = dynamic(() => import('../components/modal.tsx'), {
  ssr: false,
})

...

Is there a way I can avoid having to declare the dynamic import twice in both of these component files?
